# Generating synthetic data out of real data (For Regression Problem)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

[image]

My dataset looks like the info provided in the picture. This is a regression problem where I have to predict 'LOS' (last column). My dataset consists of around 2000 samples or rows. I would love to create more rows(synthetic-data) out of real data to improve my model result.

I found its quite easy for classification task but having difficulties for regression cases.

Any help in python environment would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be useful, https://towardsdatascience.com/part-1-balancing-and-augmenting-structured-data-4ade0df38662...

Comment: I believe its focusing classification problems.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `SMOGN`

From [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/smogn/):

> A Python implementation of Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique for Regression with Gaussian Noise (SMOGN). Conducts the Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique for Regression (SMOTER) with traditional interpolation, as well as with the introduction of Gaussian Noise (SMOTER-GN).

But take it look [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67829/data-augmentation-solutions-for-tabular-structured-data) before implementing the same.

Comment: Definite upvote for oversampling. I've not used this library but the technique is valid.

Comment: It says Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique along with three different scenarios. Unfortunately, two cases downsample the data and in one case which upsampled the data did not work for me.  However, it might work for different other application. I wish there were few others out there.